# How can Kafka be used for transferring files between servers?

Tags: synchronization, apache-kafka, rsync, apache-kafka-connect

I'm looking for a solution to keep a bunch files constantly synchronized between multiple servers (one "master" and multiple "replicas").

I've already found and successfully tested **lsyncd** https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd which is based on ssh and rsync.

However, I wanted to check if out there I could find a solution with a higher throughput.

I've started looking into **Kafka** (which is basically a message broker) and I was wondering if Kafka can be configured to be useful for this use-case. If so, how? Are you aware of an existing solution based om Kafka? Are there specific tools/plugins I should use?

Comment: What kind of files are you talking about? How large? (Kafka has a max message size) Sync how? (Kakfa is append only, so you can't sync changes in the middle without sending the whole file again). Maybe something like Resillo (Bittorrent Sync) makes more sense.

Comment: It's small files (less than 1MB), so it would be ok to sync the whole file from scratch. No need to have complex sync algorithms in my opinion.

Comment: Well, you can use Kafka Connect as a File Source + Sink, however I believe that only tails files, it doesn't respect complete modifications. At least not out of the box. You're welcome to write your own connector pair to do so

Comment: Follow up to earlier comment. Resillo is proprietary, and Syncthing is a decent alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Kafka doesn't natively support this kind of use-case out of the box.

Although it is possible to write a connector for that, I think a different solution would be more appropriate.

To the best of my knowledge, currently suitable solutions are:

- use a network file system such as NFS
- sync files via rsync/scp using a tool such as lsyncd
- if these files are JSON documents, use a NoSQL database based on JSON documents (such as MongoDB or CouchBase) and setup replication